# Can't get order object in sales_order_place_after observer method

Tags: magento-1.8, event-observer

I'm trying to hook into the `sales_order_place_after` method in my observer and save information about the just placed order into a new database table. I'm able to hook into the event successfully, but when I try to access the order object, I keep getting the error `User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back`.

This is my config.xml:

```
  <sales_order_place_after>
    <observers>
      <myaction_save_order>
        <type>singleton</type>
        <class>mymodule/observer</class>
        <method>saveOrderIdToAttendees</method>
      </myaction_save_order>
    </observers>
  </sales_order_place_after>
```

This works fine. The problem I'm getting is in my observer:

```
public function saveOrderIdToAttendees($observer) {
    $this->getHelper()->log('Helloooo');

    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

    $this->getHelper()->log($order);
}
```

For some reason I don't even have access to the `getEvent()` method. I've tried logging just the `$observer->getEvent()` object and that gives me the same error.

Comment: Can you add your entire config.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest the event `checkout_submit_all_after` in this case. As far as a I know `sales_order_place_after` is triggered when you have placed an order  using *Multishipping* but `checkout_submit_all_after` will always get triggered.

```
<global>
<events>
        <checkout_submit_all_after>
            <observers>
                <myaction_save_order>
                    <class>mymodule/observer</class>
                    <method>saveOrderIdToAttendees</method>
                </myaction_save_order>
            </observers>
        </checkout_submit_all_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

and use

```
 $order = $observer->getEvent()->getData('order');
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. Just curious, is there any particular reason to take out the `<type>singleton</type>`?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34395/magento-event-observers-singleton-versus-model

Comment: hi you can use singleton

Comment: @AmitBera will this event only trigger after payment process?

Comment: no immediate after order place..

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the observer is called before the order is actually saved to the database.  Try `sales_order_save_commit_after` for an event which is called after the MySQL transaction has been completed.