# Class observer in config.xml doesn't work

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, event-observer

I have some issue in my Event Observer in config.xml whose the class doesn't work:

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Prince_Cart>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Prince_Cart>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <cart>
                <class>Prince_Cart_Model</class>
            </cart>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <prince_cart_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Prince_Cart</module>
                </setup>
            </prince_cart_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index>
                <observers>
                    <Prince_Cart_Model_Observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>prince_cart/observer</class> <!--This doesn't work-->
                        <!--<class>Prince_Cart_Model_Observer</class>--> <!--This works but is not a good practice! -->
                        <method>blockProceedToCheckout</method>
                    </Prince_Cart_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Another detail: in which case we know that we can put `<type>singleton</type>` or `<type>model</type>` or nothing ?

**Observer.php**

```
class Prince_Cart_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer {

    public function blockProceedToCheckout($observer){
        ...
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just this seems wrong:

```
<class>prince_cart/observer</class>
```

It should fit to your block declaration:

```
<models>
    <cart>
        <class>Prince_Cart_Model</class>
    </cart>
</models>
```

Either change your observer class to:

```
<class>cart/observer</class>
```

or declare your block with `prince_cart`:

```
<models>
    <prince_cart>
        <class>Prince_Cart_Model</class>
    </prince>
</models>
```

If you remove `<type>...</type>`, it will be called as `singleton` by default. For answering `singleton` or `model` this may help: [Magento Event Observers: Singleton versus Model](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34395/magento-event-observers-singleton-versus-model)

Answer (score 0):

Your xml should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Prince_Cart>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Prince_Cart>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
          <cart>
            <class>Prince_Cart_Helper</class>
          </cart>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <cart>
                <class>Prince_Cart_Model</class>
            </cart>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <prince_cart_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Prince_Cart</module>
                </setup>
            </prince_cart_setup>
        </resources>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
                <observers>
                    <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index_handler>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>cart/observer</class>
                        <method>blockProceedToCheckout</method>
                    </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index_handler>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Your `Prince/Cart/Model/Observer.php` should look like this :

```
<?php
class Prince_Cart_Model_Observer
{
    public function blockProceedToCheckout(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        //Your logic
    }
}
```

Your `Prince/Cart/Helper/Data.php` should look like this :

```
<?php
class Prince_Cart_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

Regarding observer type :

model: a new instance of the observer class is instantiated for each event and the observer method of that instance is executed.

singleton: a single instance of the observer class is instantiated and the observer method of that single instance is executed for each event.

Comment: Thanks for you time, but why all this ? the helper ok I had it I just removed it for stack but why you replace the `<Prince_Cart_Model_Observer>` by `<controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index_handler>` and the `<events>`was in `<frontend>` ?

Comment: just for naming conventions nothing else

Comment: You can use any unique identifier instead

Comment: Why to remove `extends Varien_Event_Observer`?